# Upgrading EE from very old version to current

Tags: ee, update

I have an inherited a very old EE multisite installation that is currently running on EE 2.11.3. Due to its old version of Bootstrap, it isn't even responsive. I was thinking about upgrading to the current, open-source version 5.2.4. I can only imagine how many things could potentially break such as the templates and/or add-ons.

Does anyone have experience upgrading from such an old version of EE and is it even advisable? Thanks for any insight you may have, I am completely new to the EE community.

Comment: Show us a list of addons (extensions + plugins + modules). And v  2.11.3 is not old ) trust me. When you update from version 1.x - this is old.

Answer (score 3):

I've done several EE 2.X upgrades to 4.X and 5.X in the last few years, and on some pretty big sites to boot. It is non-trivial, but you can totally do it. Rather the retype a bunch of info, I laid out some strategies I've used successfully in this answer:

[Upgrade a site from EE2 to EE5](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41390/upgrade-a-site-from-ee2-to-ee5/41391#41391)

If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask a new question or edit this one.